# OCaml code transformed through my PPX syntax extension can't find other packages

Tags: ocaml, ppx

So, I've written a simple PPX for OCaml that transforms a silly DSL into some library calls

```
[%jsx div]
```

Becomes something like

```
ReactJS.create_element "div"
```

However, whenever I attempt to compile it, I get 'Unbound value ReactJS.create_element'. Strangely, though, if I get it to output the transformed code, then copy that code directly into the file, it compiles fine.

Do PPX syntax extensions need to be linked to any libraries their generated AST references? Am I missing something really silly?

I'm building my project with the following simple ocamlbuild command:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind \
    -package react,js_of_ocaml,js_of_ocaml.ppx \
    -package reactjs,reactjs_ppx \
    tutorial.byte tutorial.ml
```

And the PPX is generated/installed via oasis.

Anybody have any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably created the longident wrong. You should use `Longident.parse`. If that is not the case, please link to your code.

Are you aware of [Tyxml](https://ocsigen.org/tyxml/dev/manual/) and, in particular, the [ppx syntax extension](https://ocsigen.org/tyxml/dev/manual/ppx) ?

Comment: You are indeed right - I was manually constructing the Lidents.

I'll have to take a peek at Tyxml

Comment: Incoming OCaml 4.03.0 has several invariant checks against PPX outputs.  Hopefully this kind of "PPX output fails to compile, but I see nothing wrong in its _textual_ output" issues will be detected easier.